# Custom "Share to" view in Android

Tags: android

Hello I am developing an android app and I do not want to use the system "Share to" window, I want to customize it. 
So is there any way to get a list of possible share intents and put them in a custom ListView Layout ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can.

The first step is to build the sharing intent:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
```

And then, instead of creating a chooser intent, you ask the package manager for the activities that can service the `sendIntent`:

```
List<ResolveInfo> infos = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);
```

This will give you the list of activities (apps) that the chooser would also show.

You can get the app's icon and label from `ResolveInfo` and show them in a list to the user:

```
ResolveInfo info; 
Drawable icon = info.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
String label = info.loadLabel(getPackageManager());
```

Once the user has selected a `ResolveInfo` you can enrich your `sendIntent` with the selected activity to handle your intent and then start the activity:

```
sendIntent.setClassName(info.activityInfo.packageName, info.activityInfo.name);
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

We asked the system which activities can handle `sendIntent` and then let the user pick one of them. So, by definition, that activity can handle `sendIntent`. Setting the class name of the activity on the `sendIntent` sends the intent directly to that activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `resolveActivity()` method in `Intent` class. So you have to create an Intent to share some content as you do it for now, but instead calling `startActivity()` you can retrieve matching Activities by calling `resolveActivity()`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#resolveActivity%28android.content.pm.PackageManager%29

With Activity informations you can build your custom Share dialog/screen.

### EDIT

Sorry for my mistake - `resolveActivity` returns only one ComponentName - so you retrieve just package name and not a list but just one object. If you want to retrieve complete info about Activities (multiple activities matching your Intent) you should use `PackageManager.queryIntentActivities()` - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29

Comment: Please check my edit, because my first thought was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

this post can be helpful for you.

http://clickclickclack.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/intercepting-androids-action_send-intents/